# Should I embed 32 and 64 bits of lib for architecture i386 and x86_64

Tags: java, c++, xcode, cpu-architecture, dylib

I have a xcode project I compile under architectures 32 and 64 bits (my ARCHS variable has the value i386 x86_64).

I need to use a library to launch a Java 7 VM with JNI (say libinstrument.dylib). But the fact is this dylib is compiled in only one architecture (in my case 64bits). The linker is complaining about the architecture, telling me the following:

```
ld: warning: in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

How can I do to solve this problem? Should I find a 32 bits version of this lib and include it to my project, so that I will have 32 and 64 bits versions of the lib?

Previously, I used to do it for Java 6 VM, for which Apple provided a framework including the 2 architectures of this lib. But this is no more the case with Java 7, provided by Oracle.

Comment: I guess the problem boils down to: you want to target the MacOS platform and Oracle does not provide a 32 bits runtime. You can try to find a 32 bits version of the library but then you still do not have a compatible runtime to launch. IMO to me that would simply result in that for the MacOS platform you can only support a 64 bits version of your project.

Comment: You're probably right. It's the conclusion I was about to reach, and you confirm my idea. I could support 32 and 64 bits with Apple JVM 1.6, but Oracle one is only distributed in 64 bits.

Comment: Correct. Probably because the versions of MacOS they support do not even have a 32 bits architecture? To support older releases of MacOS you'd have to put yourself in the very difficult position of supporting both the old Apple runtime and the newer Oracle runtime.